# EMAILS not delivered (sent via phpMailer lite)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, mailchimp

I am sending both html and text mime parts trough gmail smtp...(my domain is registered and setup for gmail)

the mails are coming to gmail (in SPAM folder) and not coming to some other mail inboxes (hotmail for one)...

```
$mail = new PHPMailerLite();
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";

$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->SetFrom($this->CONF["appemail"], $this->CONF["appemail_from"]);


$mail->Host = "smtp.mydomain.com";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "info@mydomain.com";
$mail->Password = "*****"; 

$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = $subject;

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->Send();
```

I tried qMail, SMTPAuth true, etc... nothing works!

It is not mass mailing, just simple registration confirmation emails...

I tried mail chimp, sending trough API... and the same mail gets delivered (to hotmail too)... but Mail Chimp is not ment for sending single mails and it's a bit slow and impractical (since you have to create campaigns on the fly)....

Any other ideas?

EDIT =====================================
I tried using just php mail function with same results... gmail comes to spam, hotmail doesnt come at all

here is the (LATEST) original test msg (only html)...

```
Delivered-To: xy@gmail.com
Received: by 10.220.150.212 with SMTP id z20cs54012vcv;
        Mon, 31 Oct 2011 12:55:34 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.236.155.104 with SMTP id i68mr19074448yhk.61.1320090932659;
        Mon, 31 Oct 2011 12:55:32 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <apache@localhost.localdomain>
Received: from localhost.localdomain ([91.185.208.219])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id k64si13327245yhm.46.2011.10.31.12.55.31
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Mon, 31 Oct 2011 12:55:32 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 91.185.208.219 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of apache@localhost.localdomain) client-ip=91.185.208.219;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 91.185.208.219 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of apache@localhost.localdomain) smtp.mail=apache@localhost.localdomain
Received: from localhost.localdomain (MYDOMAIN [127.0.0.1])
    by localhost.localdomain (8.13.8/8.13.8) with ESMTP id p9VJtU07022212
    for <xy@gmail.com>; Mon, 31 Oct 2011 20:55:31 +0100
Received: (from apache@localhost)
    by localhost.localdomain (8.13.8/8.13.8/Submit) id p9VJtULP022211;
    Mon, 31 Oct 2011 20:55:30 +0100
Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2011 20:55:30 +0100
Message-Id: <201110311955.p9VJtULP022211@localhost.localdomain>
To: xy@gmail.com
Subject: MYDOMAIN.com - Registracija
From: webmaster@example.com
Reply-To: webmaster@example.com
X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.8MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>subject</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body style="font-size:12px; font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;">
        <table style="border:3px solid #8E89A3;">
            <tr style="border:3px solid #fff; background-color: #fff;">
                <td style="width: 150px; background-color: #524E63; vertical-align: bottom;"><img src="http://MYDOMAIN.com/media/mail_bg.png" /></td>
                <td style="width:auto; padding:15px 20px;">
                    <h4 style="color:#000 !important; font-size:16px !important; font-weight: bold !important;">ÄŒestitke</h4>
<p>Le Å¡e korak vas loÄi, da postanete MYDOMAIN.</p>


<p style="margin-top:20px;">VaÅ¡a registracijska koda je<br>
<b>{code}</b>
</p>


<p style="margin-top:30px;">Kliknite na spodnjo povezavo<br>
<a href="{url}">{url}</a>
</p>

                    <p style="margin-top:50px;">Prijazen pozdrav<br /><b>Ekipa MYDOMAINja</b></p>

                    <p class="footer" style="font-size:10px !important; color:#999; margin-top:30px;">
                        Podjetje: <b>MYDOMAIN d.o.o. Napredni spletni oglasnik</b> - ggggggg: <br />
                        Web: <a href="http://MYDOMAIN.com" style="color:#666 !important;">http://MYDOMAIN.com</a> - E-mail: <a href="mailto:info@MYDOMAIN.com" style="color:#666 !important;">info@MYDOMAIN.com</a> -   Tel: <b>05xxxx</b>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT2: --------------- ADDING MSG FROM phpmailer lite..... the one that DO comes in gmail INBOX and does not come to hotmail

```
Delivered-To: x.y@gmail.com
Received: by 10.220.150.212 with SMTP id z20cs54409vcv;
        Mon, 31 Oct 2011 13:07:23 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.236.22.33 with SMTP id s21mr19191499yhs.70.1320091642527;
        Mon, 31 Oct 2011 13:07:22 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <info@MYDOMAIN.com>
Received: from localhost.localdomain ([91.185.208.219])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id d30si18816984yhl.99.2011.10.31.13.07.20
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Mon, 31 Oct 2011 13:07:21 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@MYDOMAIN.com designates 91.185.208.219 as permitted sender) client-ip=91.185.208.219;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@MYDOMAIN.com designates 91.185.208.219 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=info@MYDOMAIN.com
Received: from localhost.localdomain (MYDOMAIN [127.0.0.1])
    by localhost.localdomain (8.13.8/8.13.8) with ESMTP id p9VK7JH0022228
    for <x.y@gmail.com>; Mon, 31 Oct 2011 21:07:20 +0100
Received: (from apache@localhost)
    by localhost.localdomain (8.13.8/8.13.8/Submit) id p9VK7I72022227;
    Mon, 31 Oct 2011 21:07:18 +0100
X-Authentication-Warning: localhost.localdomain: apache set sender to info@MYDOMAIN.com using -f
To: x.y@gmail.com
Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2011 21:07:18 +0100
From: =?utf-8?Q?Me=C5=A1etar?= <info@MYDOMAIN.com>
Reply-to: =?utf-8?Q?Me=C5=A1etar?= <info@MYDOMAIN.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Me=C5=A1etar_-_Registracija?=
Message-ID: <9aa1a988936cf53868568b275c29e728@MYDOMAIN.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer Lite 5.1 (phpmailer.codeworxtech.com)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_9aa1a988936cf53868568b275c29e728"


--b1_9aa1a988936cf53868568b275c29e728
Content-Type: text/plain; charset = "utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

ÄŒestitke
Le Å¡e korak vas loÄi, da postanete MYDOMAIN.


VaÅ¡a registracijska koda je
{code}



Kliknite na spodnjo povezavo
{url}


                    Prijazen pozdravEkipa MYDOMAINja


                        Podjetje: MYDOMAIN d.o.o. Napredni spletni oglasnik - xxxx, 1000 - Ljubljana: 
                        Web: http://MYDOMAIN.com - E-mail: info@MYDOMAIN.com -  Tel: xxxx


--b1_9aa1a988936cf53868568b275c29e728
Content-Type: text/html; charset = "utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body style="font-size:12px; font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;">
        <table style="border:3px solid #8E89A3;">
            <tr style="border:3px solid #fff; background-color: #fff;">
                <td style="width: 150px; background-color: #524E63; vertical-align: bottom;"><img src="http://MYDOMAIN.com/media/mail_bg.png" /></td>
                <td style="width:auto; padding:15px 20px;">
                    <h4 style="color:#000 !important; font-size:16px !important; font-weight: bold !important;">ÄŒestitke</h4>
<p>Le Å¡e korak vas loÄi, da postanete MYDOMAIN.</p>


<p style="margin-top:20px;">VaÅ¡a registracijska koda je<br>
<b>{code}</b>
</p>


<p style="margin-top:30px;">Kliknite na spodnjo povezavo<br>
<a href="{url}">{url}</a>
</p>

                    <p style="margin-top:50px;">Prijazen pozdrav<br /><b>Ekipa MYDOMAINja</b></p>

                    <p class="footer" style="font-size:10px !important; color:#999; margin-top:30px;">
                        Podjetje: <b>MYDOMAIN d.o.o. Napredni spletni oglasnik</b> - xxxx, 1000 - Ljubljana: <br />
                        Web: <a href="http://MYDOMAIN.com" style="color:#666 !important;">http://MYDOMAIN.com</a> - E-mail: <a href="mailto:info@MYDOMAIN.com" style="color:#666 !important;">info@MYDOMAIN.com</a> -   Tel: <b>xxxx</b>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>



--b1_9aa1a988936cf53868568b275c29e728--
```

**EDIT 3** ==============================================

NVM, I am stupid as hell... phpmailer **LITE** does not include smtp capabilities :(

Comment: Why not using the regular sendmail? BTW - post here the source of the received message from your gmail

Comment: Is there a bounce message or an SMTP error while you submit the mail to gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHPmailer and not PHPMailer **LITE**

PHPMailer LITE does not have SMTP capabilities built in!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the mailserver on your host may be blocked by spam filters.
If it's shared hosting or virtual shared hosting, it's not uncommon for one of the other customers to have abused mail sending in the past and got the entire server blocked.  Happened to me with one of my hosts.

Comment: was I not clear? the mails are being sent trough gmail's smtp!

Answer (score 0):

`From: webmaster@example.com`
This is your problem. because this domain is not really exists - GMail guessing it's spam and put it in that folder, other services just not so kind as GMail..

Comment: yes, I corrected this for regular mail, but not working either... check the hode before... when sending with php mailer all this data is set... I will append the poriginal msg from phpmailer lite

Answer (score 0):

as per the new SMTP rule has implemented on all mail servers i.e. you need to setup the from email address same as which define / register & Valid at that mail server. you can't spam with any other email address or domain name :

e.g. if you have email account at google as abc@gmail.com and you setup all SMTP setting and all. in few months ago we can override the from address from SMTP API zyx@gmail.com and the SMTP API will work.

but now you can't do that.